# Converting MVC-3 project to windows azure

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, azure

I have a project in MVC-3 which i am going to convert in Windows Azure project and will use blob storage.

My question is that i have some user specific information in my project which is stored in ASP.NET profile and in database table. Like images names uploaded by specific user and others. So while changing we will remove this profile and database table info also. Or keep this information as it is or just changing the location on which the images and other data save ( means from on-premises hard-disk to Windows Azure data center. )

Sorry if this is the odd question but i am pretty new in Azure. So can any body please explain me ?

Comment: Blob for files.  For structured data you have SQL Azure and Azure Table Storage (ATS).  If you just have some simple keys then ATS may be all you need - it is cheaper than SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest method would be to use SQL Database (previously known as SQL Azure) and edit your connection string pointing to SQL Database (from on-premise SQL database). You will also need to migrate your SQL database schema/data from on-premise to SQL Database. This way your migration will be much easier and you would not need to make any significant changes to your code.

If you decide to use Azure Table Storage, the you will do significant changes to your code to store user specific data to a key-value pair type of storage (i.e. Azure Table Storage), depend on how complex your tables is, this may be a choice or may not be.

As you mentioned that you have user specific information in ASP.NET profile/database tables however i think you application also require users to upload images so this is also important factor while migrating your application. While migrating your MVC3 application to Windows Azure Cloud Services, you would need to move images or any static content you keep on local disk based storage to Windows Azure Blob Storage (persisted network storage) so the code change will require to read and write data to and from Azure Blob storage, in lpace of your local machine storage. This is also a must code change in your code otherwise the image data uploaded by user will not persist and prone to lost if VM reimaged due to several other reasons.

Others may have different idea but I would personally prefer using SQL Database as a choice to reduce complexity during migration as you could pretty much migrate your database table to SQL Database with just a few lines of code change.